# Prevent flexbox items from overflowing into siblings

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a one-pager site, which is working quite well. I have three sections that need to be fullscreen, that works. But when I resize the window to 500px width and make the height also shorter, the title from the second page comes up on the first page. Same thing happens with the title on the third page, this one displays on the second page.

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWaxMK

HTML:

```
<section>
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
            </div>
</section>
<section>
            <h2 class="blue">Title 2</h2>
            <div class="box circle"></div>
            <div class="box circle"></div>
            <div class="box circle"></div>
</section>
<section>
            <h2 class="white">Title 3</h2>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
html,
    body,main {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    section {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: #ececec;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex; /* default: row nowrap */
        flex-flow:row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
    }
    section:nth-child(1) {
        background: #06a2cb;
    }
    section:nth-child(2) {
        background: #ececec;
    }
    section:nth-child(3) {
        background: #F5E5D8;
    }
    h2{
        margin-top:0;
      font-family: 'Lobster';
        margin: 1em;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
      color: black;

    }
    .box{
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #ececec;
        border-radius: 10px;
        flex: 0 0 250px;
    }
    .circle{
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: white;
 }
```

[image: Problem when resizing page using flexbox]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does changing your `section` to `display:inline-flex;` help at all?

Comment: That’s probably because the content you have does not fit into 100% of the viewport height. You should rather be using a `min-height` for your `section` elements instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem by making all the `section` elements flex items, and giving them a minimum height.

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  min-height: 100%; /* alternatively, try `min-height: 100vh` */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxwMZe)

Comment: `min-height: 100%;` alone did the job :)

Comment: Yes, theoretically I agree with you. Except when I was testing the codepen in Chrome the overlapping was still occurring a bit. That's why I added the `flex-shrink`. Then it worked perfectly. Anyway, consider it a back-up if necessary.